# Many-to-Many Relationship Against a Single, Large Table

Tags: sql, database-design, database-schema, database-normalization

I have a geometric diagram the consists of 5,000 cells, each of which is an arbitrary polygon.  My application will need to save many such diagrams.

I have determined that I need to use a database to make indexed queries against this map.  Loading all the map data is far too inefficient for quick responses to simple queries.

I've added the cell data to the database.  It has a fairly simple structure:

```
CREATE TABLE map_cell (
map_id INT  NOT NULL ,
cell_index INT  NOT NULL ,

...    
PRIMARY KEY (map_id, cell_index)
)
```

5,000 rows per map is quite a few, but queries should remain efficient into the millions of rows because the main join indexes can be clustered.  If it gets too unwieldy, it can be partitioned on map_id bounds.  Despite the large number of rows per map, this table would be quite scalable.

The problem comes with storing the data that describes which cells neighbor each other.  The cell-neighbor relationship is a many-to-many relationship against the same table.  There are also a very large number of such relationship per map.  A normalized table would probably look something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE map_cell_neighbors (
id INT  NOT NULL AUTO INCREMENT ,
map_id INT  NOT NULL ,
cell_index INT  NOT NULL ,
neighbor_index INT ,
...
INDEX IX_neighbors (map_id, cell_index)
)
```

This table requires a surrogate key that will never be used in a join, ever.  Also, this table includes duplicate entries:  if cell 0 is a neighbor with cell 1, then cell 1 is always a neighbor of cell 0.  I can eliminate these entries, at the cost of some extra index space:

```
CREATE TABLE map_cell_neighbors (
id INT  NOT NULL AUTO INCREMENT ,
map_id INT  NOT NULL ,
neighbor1 INT  NOT NULL ,
neighbor2 INT  NOT NULL ,
...
INDEX IX_neighbor1 (map_id, neighbor1),
INDEX IX_neighbor2 (map_id, neighbor2)
)
```

I'm not sure which one would be considered more "normalized", since option 1 includes duplicate entries (including duplicating any properties the relationship has), and option 2 is some pretty weird database design that just doesn't feel normalized.  Neither option is very space efficient.  For 10 maps, option 1 used 300,000 rows taking up 12M of file space. Option 2 was 150,000 rows taking up 8M of file space.  On both tables, the indexes are taking up more space than the data, considering the data should be about 20 bytes per row, but it's actually taking 40-50 bytes on disk.

The third option wouldn't be normalized at all, but would be incredibly space- and row-efficient.  It involves putting a VARBINARY field in map_cell, and storing a binary-packed list of neighbors in the cell table itself.  This would take 24-36 bytes per cell, rather than 40-50 bytes per relationship.  It would also reduce the overall number of rows, and the queries against the cell table would be very fast due to the clustered primary key.  However, performing a join against this data would be impossible.  Any recursive queries would have to be done one step at a time.  Also, this is just really ugly database design.

Unfortunately, I need my application to scale well and not hit SQL bottlenecks with just 50 maps.  Unless I can think of something else, the latter option might be the only one that really works.  Before I committed such a vile idea to code, I wanted to make sure I was looking clearly at all the options.  There may be another design pattern I'm not thinking of, or maybe the problems I'm foreseeing aren't as bad as they appear.  Either way, I wanted to get other people's input before pushing too far into this.

---

The most complex queries against this data will be path-finding and discovery of paths.  These will be recursive queries that start at a specific cell and that travel through neighbors over several iterations and collect/compare properties of these cells.  I'm pretty sure I can't do all this in SQL, there will likely be some application code throughout.  I'd like to be able to perform queries like this of moderate size, and get results in an acceptable amount of time to feel "responsive" to user, about a second.  The overall goal is to keep large table sizes from causing repeated queries or fixed-depth recursive queries from taking several seconds or more.

Comment: Is your principal goal space-efficiency or execution-efficiency?  And what kinds of queries do you anticipate making against this data? (examples would be nice)

Comment: My goal is to keep both within acceptable range.  Execution-efficiency is important, but I don't want to over-optimize when there are still AJAX overheads to deal with anyways.  Space-efficiency isn't hugely important if we're not talking gigabytes, but it is server space.  My principal concern is keeping large tables from crippling SQL query times.

The most complex query will be a recursive one, starting a single cell and branching outwards, and then making decisions based on the properties of these cells.  This will be done with a mix of SQL and application code.

Comment: 1) In your schema the foreign keys appear to be missing 2) the enumeration of neighbours is not needed, a simple cell-to-cell {neighbour1<-->neibour2} junction table would suffice (with two foreign keys, obviously) 3) is the graph undirected? (I suppose it is) 4) loops will always be a problem; at least in SQL.

Comment: 1) Foreign keys would definitely help. 2) map_cell_neighbors is such a junction table, minus the foreign keys.  Basically the indexes should be foreign keys.  My concern is speed when it (quickly) reaches millions of row.  3) Yes.  It is a Voronoi diagram which has been relaxed to normalize cell size.  4) I'm not sure I can escape the need to make each iteration a separate query and to make some decisions in application code.  I could perhaps use sub-queries to dig up to a fixed depth, but I'm well aware of the problems with SQL loops.  I'd much rather do such things in application code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure which database you are using, but you seem to be re-inventing what a spatial enabled database supports already.

If SQL Server, for example, is an option, you could store your polygons as geometry types, use the built-in spatial indexing, and the OGC compliant methods such as "STContains", "STCrosses", "STOverlaps", "STTouches".

SQL Server spatial indexes, after decomposing the polygons into various b-tree layers, also uses tessellation to index which neighboring cells a given polygon touches, at a given layer of the tree-index.

There are other mainstream databases which support spatial types as well, including [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/spatial-extensions.html)

Comment: This is definitely the kind of thing I was looking for.  I wasn't aware that such features existed.  My application is running on a Linux web server running MySQL.  It looks like MySQL offers such features as well.  I'll look into the details.

Comment: Question: is it really very efficient to be using these spacial relationship tests in WHERE clauses?  My queries would something like this:  "SELECT * FROM map_cell c1 LEFT JOIN map_cell c2 ON c1.map_id = c2.map_id AND Touches(c1.geom, c2.geom)" to return all neighbors for a specific cell. Would it be capable of handling such  a query optimally assuming there are 100,000+ rows in the table and 5,000 rows that meet the c1.map_id=c2.map_id criteria?

Comment: I'm familiar with SQL Server but not MySQL, so I cannot be specific. Speaking abstractly, using a spatial enabled db engine to execute that query will be the most optimized approach, instead of trying to execute large non-spatial recursions. More specifically, the question of performance is answered by better clarification of your needs. Is it a one time query? Is it something dynamic that would be executed for only one cell at a time? If the map data is static, you might be able to create a table that houses the cartesian product of all touching cells and fill it once (or update periodically)

Comment: Queries will often be recursive.  I'll regularly need to branch out from one or more cell locations, and find all cells within a certain range (like finding all cells within sight range or mobility range).  The map diagram is fixed.  Once generated, the cell properties may change, but the structure of the diagram will never change.  If two cells are neighbors, they will always remain so.  However, the Cartesian product is 15,000 relationships per map, and I am concerned that this will overwhelm SQL at some point.  My OP demonstrated such a table, and how quickly it would grow.

Comment: After a quick google, it does not seem that MySQL has a 'Distance' function, which SQL Server does. Nonetheless...I encourage you to work with the geometry type and functions a bit first. Think in sets (or in this case, a 'set' of cells might be quantified as a bounding box) and likely you can eliminate the recursion. Also, while the Cartesian product table might have thousands of rows, the goal would be that it eliminates any runtime calculations, and is a simple lookup indexed by cell...but pursue it only if it fits your reqmts.

Comment: The properties of the cells may affect distance.  Crossing a river would affect movement, and high elevation would affect sight.  Water cells block movement altogether.  Regardless, distance (for my purposes) is center-to-center; cell centers don't require geometry objects, and distance is easy to calculate.  I could do this if I want to make most of the decisions in application code, but this code would still need all the neighbor data.  Either way, this gives me plenty of ideas.  I'm going to have just try out a few things and test with a bunch of data.  Thanks for the help.